# I need help to get the Name of radio button using JavaScript not the value

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i am using below HTML for radio button question there are different option with different values

```
<div class="form-check-inline section-3">
     <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios1" value="1">
             <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios1">
                                          Never
                                  </label>
                               </div>
```

You will see the the radio button value is "1" but in screen when question appear it shows "Never" .... i want to get this Never text using Java script when i am using `$("input[name=‘question1’]:checked").val();` i am getting value which is 1 but i want text which "Never" how to get that ....

Comment: .val() = value
.text() = text 
:)

Comment: can you explain little bit ? How should i use this @MaximColesnic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let $input = $("input[name='question1']:checked");
$input.siblings(`label[for='${$input.attr('id')}']`).text();
```